# utilizar ciclos for en c++

Tags: c++

Tengo este codigo con una matriz, que me da

1 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0

0 - 1 - 0 - 0 - 0

0 - 0 - 1 - 0 - 0

0 - 0 - 0 - 1 - 0

0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 1

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>




int main(){
}




    
    int mat[5][5];
    int i,j;
    
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
        if (i==j)
        {
            mat[i][j] = 1; 
       }
        else
        {
           mat [i][j] = 0;
        }
       }
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
      printf("| %i \t",mat[i][j]);
      
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

    
}
```

mi pregunta es, como hacerlo que de

0 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 1

0 - 0 - 0 - 1 - 0

0 - 0 - 1 - 0 - 0

0 - 1 - 0 - 0 - 0

1 - 0 - 0 - 0 - 0

no me da por mas que le muevo, gracias saludos

Answer (score 4):

Antes de nada, idealmente deberías sacar ese número 5 que tienes a machete a una constante

```
#define NCOLUMNAS 5
```

Tu condición para que te escriba 1 en la diagonal ArribaIzquierda->AbajoDerecha es que i sea igual a j.

Al buscar la otra diagonal, la condición es un poquillo más difícil.

Lo que tienes que hacer es tratar de buscar la expresión en base a variables o constantes que ya tengas. Asumiendo que la matriz es cuadrada, de lo que depende que una casilla se pinte con 1 o 0 es:

- Su fila (i)
- Su columna (j)
- El número de columnas de la matriz (NCOLUMNAS)

Por lo que hay que buscar una expresión que utilice estas variables para que de true o false en el caso que te interese.

```
Para la fila 0 (i=0), quiero que se ponga a 1 la columna 4 (NCOLUMNAS - 1 - 0)
Para la fila 1 (i=1), quiero que se ponga a 1 la columna 3 (NCOLUMNAS - 1 - 1)
Para la fila 2 (i=2), quiero que se ponga a 1 la columna 2 (NCOLUMNAS - 1 - 2)
Para la fila 3 (i=3), quiero que se ponga a 1 la columna 1 (NCOLUMNAS - 1 - 3)
Para la fila 4 (i=4), quiero que se ponga a 1 la columna 0 (NCOLUMNAS - 1 - 4)
```

Fijate al final de la expresión, primero restamos 0, luego, 1, luego 2, luego 3 y luego 4, **que es lo mismo que restarle `i`**, ya que primero es 0, luego 1, luego 2, luego 3 y luego 4.

Por lo que en vez de

`if (i==j)`

podemos usar esta condición:

`if (j == NCOLUMNAS - 1 - i)`

de esa manera se muestra la diagonal inversa:

```
| 0     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 1 
| 0     | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0 
| 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 0 
| 0     | 1     | 0     | 0     | 0 
| 1     | 0     | 0     | 0     | 0
```

Comment: No se como implementar eso con un define, es que soy nuevo y la verdad me cuesta

Comment: Lo único que tenderías que hacer es poner ese `#define` que te he puesto debajo de los `#include`s y donde tengas un 5 sustituirlo por `NCOLUMNAS`. Si lo haces de esa manera, si quieres cambiar a una matriz de 6x6 solo tendrías que cambiar el valor en el `#define`, no en cada sitio donde hubieses puesto un 5.

Comment: Thanks!!! De buena fe te agradezco

Answer (score 0):

Para rellenar una matriz con una diagonal descendente, tienes que sumar 1 al índice de columna por cada fila que recorres, empezando en la esquina superior izquierda (fila cero, columna cero) obviamente.

Para la diagonal ascendente tienes dos opciones:

1. Restar 1 al índice de columna por cada fila que recorres, empezando en la esquina superior derecha (fila cero, columna cuatro).
2. Sumar 1 al índice de columna por cada fila que recorres, pero recorrer las filas al reves.

Voy a ponerte un ejemplo de la segunda opción pero con un código más moderno, primero una función para mostrar la matriz:

```
template <int TAMANYO>
void mostrar(int (&matriz)[TAMANYO][TAMANYO])
{
    for (const auto &fila : matriz)
    {
        for (const auto &valor: fila)
            std::cout << valor;
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Y ahora rellenar la diagonal recorriendo las filas desde abajo:

```
template <int TAMANYO>
void diagonal_ascendente(cont int (&matriz)[TAMANYO][TAMANYO])
{
    int columna = 0;
    for (auto fila = std::rbegin(matriz), fin = std::rend(matriz); fila != fin; ++fila)
    {
        (*fila)[columna++] = 1;
    }
}
```

El único código que necesitas en `main` es este:

```
int main()
{
    int mat[5][5]{};

    std::cout << "Antes:\n";
    mostrar(mat);

    std::cout << "\nDespues:\n";
    diagonal_ascendente(mat);
    mostrar(mat);

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFBT4NAEIXP7K8Ya9JS0UQPXoA2IfGqXryYtjHjsiWbLLNkWXqw4bfjLqUkFmNMOMC8b2beG3hV3XGFVHTdtSSumlxAKnVtjcByzZgVZaXQ@iJZeMues5f31zU7aJlD6TE0oVfCeYnWyK/lZmB248uSHVmw1wZCrqm2gI3VMN9LhRDD0MUCx0yhAyptYvCsQ4Kgtnkcc91YSFPoxYRdVBdbWrhiy9q/zecSC02oPrDmgnJBVvwriGe4Vk1JCCu4T4Zovd8@0wp6P@ZTFJLCYdit02iU3L6zkJyarlYeSCCKhqz@HOFN/7EZ1kXRzk14OIdjzFsp0S0Zjbmhm8ede45twtjPw8wyF7GOtzRzE86/zjUsp@SWnkRdNSP9261OnZNBRtjGkL9L23Xf)</kbd>.

### Explicación.

Estamos pasando una matriz por referencia a las funciones. La sintaxis para tener una referencia a matriz es:

```
tipo (&nombre)[tamaño];
```

El ejemplo anterior es una referencia (`&`) a una matriz de tipo `tipo` con tamaño `tamaño`. Como queremos una matriz cuadrada pondremos dos tamaños que serán el mismo. Al pasar el tamaño como parámetro de plantilla, podemos usar la plantilla para matrices de cualquier tamaño.

En la función `diagonal_ascendente` conseguimos recorrer las filas de abajo a arriba usando el iterador inverso ([`std::reverse_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator)), que recorre colecciones de datos en sentido inverso. Puedes crear un iterador inverso sobre una colección de datos usando la función [`std::rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/rbegin).